# Can't use Windows after shutting down PC during dual-boot Ubuntu instalation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

So I was installing dual-boot Ubuntu, but it was stuck so I shut down my PC while installing and turned it on again. Now, whenever I don't have the USB drive (containing Ubuntu) plugged in, my PC goes into the BIOS settings instead of Windows 10. How can I use Windows again?

Also, my grub.cfg is in /cdrom/boot/grub and this is my filesystem: https://pastebin.com/32SJN00j

Comment: Question is, where did you install grub? On your "main" disk or on that USB stick?

Comment: @kanehekili wdym?

Comment: At the end of the installation process, the "installer" asks you **where** to install the grub. If you selected sth else than "sda"(or nvme), the bootloader "grub" is installed on your stick. That means your PC only runs if your stick is inserted. (since the windows bootloader has been removed by that installation)

Comment: @kanehekili i don't remember being asked anything about grub in the installer.

Comment: Start your PC (with your stick) and search for "grub.cfg". It should be in "/boot/grub/". Find out where that folder resides. (Use `df .`for this - cd into your /boot/grub)
To get a map of your system: also execute `df -h`. Paste both outputs into your question by using the **edit** link below your question

Comment: If Windows and Ubuntu are installed in different BIOS/UEFI modes, GRUB will not boot Windows.

Comment: @kanehekili i do have "grub.cfg" but it's in /cdrom/boot/grub rather than just /boot/grub. and the df -h results are in the question body, now

Answer (score 0):

That looks strange, your "main" disk is not even mounted. What you see is only your USB stick. You need to install Ubuntu "besides" Windows. Since Windows is probably installed in UEFI, Ubuntu needs to be installed as UEFI as well. When installing you need to make sure that the windows partition is large enough for another OS.

Many years ago I had to stop hibernation of windows in order to remove a "hibernate.sys" file to get enough space.

You should look into your bios/uefi if your "main disk" is still in the boot order. An make sure that Ubuntu is installed in the same mode as Windows (either BIOS or UEFI)